# jQuery NewBie Questions: What's the deal with $(document).(ready)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am newbie to `jQuery`, just trying to learn it since last couple of days. In my office, there are few experience JavaScript Developer and they work mainly with `jQuery` for all their needs and whenever I got and talk to them to get some better understanding of how `jQuery` works and first they say is that on `$(document).(ready)` you do this and on `$(document).(ready)` you do that.

So my main question is What is the `$(document).(ready)` and how does it really works?

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

**Update**: In the accepted answers comment there is mention on *When DOM is ready*, so what does that really means ?

Comment: Check the answer from Felix King.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$(document).ready() fires once the DOM is completely loaded and ready for manipulation.  This prevents your code from firing before the objects that it'll act against exist.  $(document).ready() is the most verbose version of it, and can be replaced up with any of these statements...

```
$(document).ready(handler)
$().ready(handler) (this is not recommended)
$(handler)
$(document).bind("ready", handler)
```

See [here](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) for the documentation.

Comment: Just to be clear: `$(document).ready()` fires once the *DOM* is completely loaded, not necessarily after the *page* is loaded. This event may fire before things like images are fully downloaded.

Comment: FYI, as of jQuery 1.4, `$()` returns an empty jQuery set, so it's not equivalent to `$(document)`. Your second example won't work in 1.4.

Answer (score 3):

I think it is best described in the [tutorial](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials:How_jQuery_Works#Launching_Code_on_Document_Ready):

> **Launching Code on Document Ready**
>
> The first thing that most Javascript programmers end up doing is adding some code to their program, similar to this:
>
> ```
> window.onload = function(){ alert("welcome"); }
> ```
>
> Inside of which is the code that you want to run right when the page is loaded. **Problematically, however, the Javascript code isn't run until all images are finished downloading** (this includes banner ads). The reason for using `window.onload` in the first place is that the HTML 'document' isn't finished loading yet, when you first try to run your code.
>
> To circumvent both problems, jQuery has a simple statement that checks the document and waits until it's ready to be manipulated, known as the ready event:
>
> ```
> $(document).ready(function(){
>     // Your code here
> });
> ```

---

Or in short, it guarantees that every element of the document is loaded so that you can access it, but it does not wait until the images are loaded.

Answer (score 1):

$(document).(ready) is called once all the elements of your page are loaded.  This allows you to setup things like event handlers with confidence because you know that the elements all exist.

Answer (score 1):

Document Ready is referred to the event that gets triggered by jQuery/JavaScript **when the entire HTML document and all of its elements are loaded**, and ready for manipulation.

The way that the browser loads elements is it renders them as the page is being downloaded.  If you have some script that runs prematurely then you have a risk of that script failing.

So you use Document Ready to ensure that it only runs when the entire page is ready.

Here is an example... This will print "hello" once the entire document is done loading in your browser:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
   alert('hello');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The DOM means Document Object Model. You can read more about it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model). So

$(document).ready()

is fired  once the DOM is completely loaded by your browser.Since Javascript is executed on your browser, we would only like to start execution once  the browser knows about every element on the page on which we want the script to be executed on.

Answer (score 0):

it just like window.onload event

except it dosent wait all the binary data such image to complete loading

this is crucial if u want to work with dom,because u dosent want your code to access dom element that dosent exist